# How do you idiomatically transate 你这个人?

Tags: word-choice

I was typing something in Chinese to a friend including 你这人 (or 你这个人), when I realized that I didn't have a good interpretation of it in English. It just feels like the sort of thing you say to somebody when you're pointing out something criticizable of theirs, but I don't know how to put it in words.

Something like this: 你这人，怎么能说那个乱话呢？ (***_*__*_***, how can you say that messed-up stuff?)

Comment: Why, you little <insert word of varying level of insult>, how can you _say_ that messed up stuff?!

Comment: @StumpyJoePete Your way works too. Sounds good to my ear.

Comment: Just translate its meaning as "How dare you say that?"

Comment: Perhaps a variation of @StumpyJoePete's answer works too, just leaving out the <insert word of varying level of insult> and say "Why, you little..., how can you..." After all, it's not uncommon to omit the word of insult in English!

Answer (score 2):

```
You, how can you say that messed-up stuff?
```

or just omit that and say

```
How can you say that messed-up stuff?
```

Answer (score 2):

Just:

```
Dude! How can you say that messed-up stuff?
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
Hey you! how can you say that messed-up stuff?
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple

> Dude\Come on!\Man!\Buddy\Amigo\My friend, how can say than kind of
>   stuff?!